# Is that any social community modules or plugins available in phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am very new to phalcon php framework.In my next project i need to create a CMS with the integration of some social community features.so tell me, How phalcon is good enough to integrate social community modules like Media sharing(Image, Video, Audio),Social Grouping, Tagging, Messaging,.. etc.Is that any modules already available?

or suggest me some good php framework that lightweight, reliable, promising and more customisable 
**note:I am not interested in do this by some available social community frameworks like socialengine,elgg..etc.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phalcon is a generic full stack framework, but, not any better at or necessarily geared towards social media than any other PHP framework.

Comment: Full stack, in this case, means that the framework gives you all of the necessary foundational blocks that other frameworks may not offer. For instance, micro frameworks sometimes won't offer an ORM. Phalcon offers a very rich set of features and everything you need to not "reinvent the wheel," so to speak. while yes, I am a HUGE Phalcon fan, I recommend looking at each product objectively and selecting which one you like the best. However, what I've stated are just the facts; nothing more.

Comment: thanks eBrain your answer help me a lot to decide my way on doing things further..

Answer (score -4):

I recommend trying Laravel framework , It is a great light php framework , at least in my opinion

Comment: Most frameworks of any sort are going to have social media integrations. I'm a huge Laravel fan, but this isn't hugely helpful - they can all do this, and switching tech just means you start at the bottom of the learning curve again.

Comment: OP Asked for  good php framework that lightweight, reliable, promising and more customisable, So I did and added that it is my opinion. Thank you